# JDO Query Collection of Child Object

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I face empty result when query child property.

My child object is a list of custom object as shown below:

Parent

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table")
public class TimesheetRecordDaily{
...
    @Persistent(embeddedElement = "true", serialized = "true", defaultFetchGroup="true") 
    @Element(embedded="true") 
    private List<TimesheetRecordDailyDetailDTO> timesheetRecordDailyDetails;
...
}
```

Child

```
@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class TimesheetRecordDailyDetailDTO{
...
    @Persistent
    private String projectName;
...
}
```

Query:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(TimesheetRecordDaily.class);
query.setFilter("this.timesheetRecordDailyDetails.contains(prd) && prd.projectName == 'MyProject'");            
query.declareVariables(TimesheetRecordDailyDetailDTO.class.getName() + " prd"); 
List results = (List)query.execute();
```

If I change the query filter as below (without query child property value, result is return

```
query.setFilter("this.timesheetRecordDailyDetails.contains(prd)");
```

Any help?  Is that the problem for JDO run in GAE to query child property value?

Note: GAE version I use is 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible as I just found out, it is stated in GAE documentation that we can’t use the child entity in the filter when query on parent

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2